# Difference between shap values and feature contributions

Tags: decision-trees, prediction, interpretation, shap

I always found both concepts a bit confusing since they are quite similar. Would someone provide clear example where to apply each?

Shap values ref: https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d

Comment: The following blog article compares different ways to measure feature importance incl. SHAP. Might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-machine-learning-with-xgboost-9ec80d148d27